# The output from LPSolver is not the optimal result

Tags: r, optimization, lpsolve

Since I need to create an automatic shift planning tool, R `lpSolve` is the package I plan to use. However, I can't get the optimal output by the code shown as below. The output(hourly supply by accumulating all shifts available) can't fulfill the demand. e.g. The demand for a hour is 46 but the supply is only 25 which means 21 unit of demand can't be satisfied.

Background:

- The objective

  1. To minimize the difference between total supply and total demand.
  2. To minimize the difference between supply and demand for each hour.
- Constraint

  1. Shift constraint - each hour might have several shifts available to be assigned.
  2. Max capacity - I have the cap of supply. the sum of total shift cant exceed the cap for each hour. (46 is the cap in this example).

In the `constr` matrix, 24 rows represent 24 hours starting from 7 am and 9 columns refers to no. of shifts I have.

The `constr.val` refers to hourly demand.

Please let me know if there is anything unclear. thanks!

```
library(lpSolve)

obj.fun<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
constr<-matrix(c(
1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,
1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,
1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,
1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,
0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,
0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,
0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,
0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,
0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,
0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,
0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,
0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,
0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,
0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,
0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1,
0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,
0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,
0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0), nrow = 24, byrow = TRUE)
constr.dir <- rep("<=", 24)
constr.val <- c(24, 20, 21, 22, 26, 34, 40, 44, 
                46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 
                46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 41, 27)
day.shift <- lp("max", obj.fun, constr, constr.dir, 
                constr.val, compute.sens = TRUE)


day.shift$solution
```

Comment: You say that *the supply is only 25*  but I am not getting that. The greatest difference between demand and supply is at hour 22, with demand =  46 and supply = 27, 19 units of demand cannot be met.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Hello Rui, Sorry for the unclear explain, what i said is just an dummy example to describe the situation. but thank you for giving the real gap between demand and supply as you said. However, no matter what the gap is, it does exist and I want to minimize the gap as much as possible. May I have your suggestion how can I accomplish that? thanks